# Sharing the same page on facebook with different titles/photos. I use addThis

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This link http://new.freelanceok.com/Project/Detail/45/TestProjecSkill is not valid for sharing on facebook (title,description,image). I tried to share that from `addThis`.

Comment: That link is not browsable. It gives an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Probably that is the reason you are not able to add

Answer (score 0):

Is this your own site or different site ??

Use below url for external site , if it is your site add meta tags.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=thisismytitle&p[summary]=thisismysummary&p[url]=http://www.google.com&&p[images][0]=www.mysit/imag.jpg', 'Facebook', 'width=626,height=436,toolbar=0,status=0

Replace www.mysit/imag.jpg with image
Replace thisismytitle with your title
Replace http://www.google.com with your url
```